# Why should maximal ideals of $\mathbb{Z_9}$ be of the form $p\mathbb{Z} / 9 \mathbb{Z}$ where $p\mid 9$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I am taking a course on commutative algebra and the instructor used this result without any proof or explanation and he is not very keen to take questions of students.

So, I am asking it here.

> How can I prove that maximal ideals of $\mathbb{Z_9}$ are of the form $p\mathbb{Z} / 9 \mathbb{Z}$ where $p\mid 9$?

Definition of maximal ideal and ohter details are clear to me as I have done a course on ring theory but I am still unable to prove it.

So, guidence will be appreciated for a rigorous proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try and make the question a bit more general.

Given a proper ideal $I$ in the ring $R$, there is a bijection between the set of ideals in the ring $R/I$ and the set of ideals in $R$ that contain $I$. This bijection preserves the order. It's a consequence of the homomorphism theorems and you should be able to spell out what the bijection is.

Thus, finding the maximal ideals in $R/I$ is the same as finding the maximal ideals in $R$ that contain $I$.

In the case of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, where $n>1$, we know that the maximal ideals in $\mathbb{Z}$ have the form $p\mathbb{Z}$, for $p$ a prime. Moreover $p\mathbb{Z}\supseteq n\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if $p\mid n$.

Therefore the maximal ideals in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ are exactly those of the form $p\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for $p$ a prime dividing $n$. If $n=9$ there's only one of them, namely $3\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$.